# Validation of file path before actually opening the file

Tags: c, linux, file, validation, posix

Assuming Linux, or more generally a sufficiently POSIX compliant system, is there a ready made method of checking if opening a file with a given name would succeed? Most optimistically I am seeking an implementation of a function with the same prototype as `open(2)`

```
int test_open(const char *pathname, int flags);
```

which would return result according to anticipated success or failure of `open(2)` system call with the same parameters, but *without actually creating or opening any file*. It should be suitably licensed (reusable in proprietary software project) open source.

The [`open(2)` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) lists many reasons for `open(2)` failing. One `errno` value can decode multiple reasons, and the `errno` is different between Linux and POSIX. But nevertheless roughly speaking:

1. I think in general the following cases as itemized by `errno` are most relevant: `EACCESS`, `EEXIST`, `ENOENT`, `EISDIR`, `ENOTDIR` (both POSIX and Linux).
2. Less important: `ELOOP`, `EMFILE`, `ENFILE`, `ENAMETOOLONG`, `ENODEV`, `ENXIO`, `EOVERFLOW`, `EPERM`, `EROFS`, `ETXTBSY`, `EWOULDBLOCK` (POSIX adds `EAGAIN`).
3. Irrelevant (more transient conditions): `ENOMEM`, `EINTR`, `ENOSPC` (POSIX adds `EIO`, `ENOSR`).

(I am now unable to quickly find online POSIX manual page for `open()`, I am personally referring to POSIX manual pages installed in my Linux machine - I will edit the question when I find online link.)

**Background and Expectations:** My application/system configuration architecture mandates that an input value need to be validated before storing it permanently. Only after the validation and storage steps are performed, is the file going to be used for writing. Accepting bad values would be huge inconvenience (also trying to actually change to use bad file path would disturb the operation). I cannot or do not want to make exception for this special case (it is just one of over a hundred of configuration values).

I would prefer to not introduce side effects for the validation by creating a file (the flags for `open()` include `O_CREAT`). *It is obvious that the check I am seeking for cannot be implemented 100% reliably in the most general case*, which is the underlying reason for my categorizing the possible error conditions into three groups. We could have *a very educated guess* by analyzing the directory permissions, existence of directories, and whether there is already something with the same name which hinders opening the file, and whether the file name makes sense (my group 1 conditions). (Group 2 checks for number of symbolic links, file descriptor limits, name length limit, `O_NOATIME` permission, writability of the file system, and maybe `EWOULDBLOCK` and POSIX `EAGAIN` cases could be done but they are more cumbersome and probably less portable to do, and are expected to be less likely to happen unless evil input, which were the reasons for categorizing them less important).

P.S. I added tag `c` which is my programming language now, but the language is not very relevant.

Comment: Well I think it's a bad idea to try to check status at one stage and then just assume its gonna work at a later stage. Environment will most likely have changed. Just break out the check when you actually need to do the write and make sure you can handle the situation if it fails _when_ you actually need it. That's my tip.

Comment: @Jite - I edited my question to make it more obvious that I am not expecting fail proof way of doing this, and to explain more clearly why I need to have the validation and actual opening separate. Anyway, in my case the time between validity check and actually opening the file is short (subsecond) and the system can be expected to not undergo sudden changes (embedded Linux system with stable directory tree structure).

Comment: "when actually need it"... I do not have very obvious fail over value, but could make a build configuration for that purpose. Still I need to validate the input value, separate from the opening and writing to the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no fail-proof way to do that, because (as Jite commented) some other process could have changed the environment (e.g. removed the parent directory, or filled up the filesystem, exceeded the disk quota, ....) between your `test_open` and the further `open` or `creat` syscall. Or the disk (or the media containing the filesystem, e.g. some USB stick) could have burned or have been unplugged.

The good practice is to check the result of `open` and use `errno` when it has failed.

You could use `access` to check a few things before. But since there is no fail-proof way, why bother?

You might validate the directory part of your file path using the [realpath(3)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/realpath.3.html) function .... But even that is useless, some other process could have created or deleted the directory between your `test_open` and the real `open`

Comment: Huge thanks for reminding me of `access(2)` - this combined with use of `stat(2)` for the file (and directory) should solve big part of the problem. Funny that `open(2)` fails to mention `access(2)`. Fortunately I do not need fail-proof check in my case. I just need to have a very educated guess before accepting a path for my writable file (which will be unlikely to change for some time once configured). The manual page for `access(2)` also reminds that in general it creates a security hole, but in my case this is a small concern.

Comment: Again, it does not bring much: the user could open a terminal and do things in the file system.... Or the disk could have been almost full (or quota reached) at `test_open` time and completely full at `open`time. You *have to handle* `open` failures

Comment: Yes, clearly in the general case all kind of things can happen. There is good reason why `accept(2)` manual page warns against using the system call. However, in my case the system is embedded Linux with flash and RAM based storage only and known processes running on it. Only system developers have access to shell. The writeable file size is limited (using file rotation). If the directory tree starts to change, or strange files with weird permissions start to appear then things are abnormal and nothing can be expected to work anyway (file system corruption one possible reason).

Comment: I am handling the open failure, and could define build configuration for fail over value. The problem point just is the validation of file path before accepting and making it permanent. Though most cases when the configuration value for the file path is changed it is for the benefit of developers themselves so this inconvenience could be permissible.